# How to generate swagger documentation for 'other' URLconfs from apps included into the project urls.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I am working on a project using the following dependencies:

Python 3.7

django 2.2.6

djangorestframework 3.9.4

I am creating multiple apps and each of these apps has their own urls.py files which are included in the URLs file of the parent project. I wish to create swagger documentation for the API endpoints described in the included URLconf files. However, swagger only documents URLs mapped in the parent URLconf file.

I have already tried including the swagger view in the URLconfs of the projects but it still serves the parent URLconf only.

Basically, I have added the below code to all my URLconf's

```py
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Some APIs')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', schema_view),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION))
]
```